# Using Docker, PHP container error "Name or service not known" when attempting to connect to SQL container (mariadb)

Tags: php, mysql, docker, mariadb

I have two Docker containers running right now, "mariadb-1" running mariadb:latest (with 3307:3306 set up for ports) and "php-apache-1" running php:apache (with 81:80 set up for ports). My goal is to have PHP output the contents of an SQL table in a web page. However, when I browse to the web page I get this error:

```
Warning: mysqli::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mariadb-1 failed: Name or service not known in /var/www/html/display_data.php on line 9

Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo for mariadb-1 failed: Name or service not known in /var/www/html/display_data.php:9 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/display_data.php(9): mysqli->__construct('mariadb-1', 'root', Object(SensitiveParameterValue), 'test_db', 3307) #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/display_data.php on line 9
```

This is what I am trying to run with PHP:

```
<?php
  $host = 'mariadb-1';
  $port = 3307;
  $username = 'root';
  $password = 'xxxxxxxx';
  $database = 'test_db';
  
  // Create a connection
  $conn = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database, $port);

  // Check for connection errors
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  }
  
  // Query to fetch all entries from the table
  $query = "SELECT * FROM test_table";
  $result = $conn->query($query);
  
  // Check for query errors
  if (!$result) {
      die("Query error: " . $conn->error);
  }
  
  // Output the entries
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo "ID: " . $row['id'] . " | Text: " . $row['text_field'] . "<br>";
  }
  
  // Close the connection
  $conn->close();
?>
```

Both containers can ping the other from their terminals in Docker Desktop (I am using Docker Desktop on an M1 Mac). In fact, as an experiment I used `apt` to install `mariadb` on the "php-apache-1" container and used that to remotely access the mariadb database in the other container, although I did use the internal IP address instead of the hostname/container name to do so. So I am fairly sure it is a PHP problem of some type, but I don't know where or why. I have tried replacing `$host` with the internal 172.17.0.x IP address as well but that doesn't work either.

Using port 3306 gives the same error, as does removing the "port" line altogether and letting it use whatever it thinks the default port should be.

I also am not working from a compose file; I have just been building containers one-by-one mostly as an academic exercise for myself.

Comment: Show your compose file.

Comment: Connections between containers always use the standard port for the destinadion service; port mappings aren't considered (or required).  Does changing `$port = 3306` to the standard MySQL port work?

Comment: Not sure it explains the error you are seeing, but `3307` is the port to access the container from the host.  From another container, you would use `3306`.  [From the docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/): "*Networked service-to-service communication uses the CONTAINER_PORT*" (where CONTAINER_PORT is the default port of the service inside the container).